# Calculating $(a \bmod b) \bmod p$ when $(a \bmod p) \bmod b$ is given

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there any way to find out $(a \bmod b) \bmod p$ when $(a \bmod p) \bmod b$ is given, where $p$ is a prime number and $b\ <\ p$.

For example:

when $a = 142,\ b = 8\ \text{and}\ p = 19$

So $(142 \bmod 19) \bmod 8 = 1$.

How can I calculate $(142 \bmod 8) \bmod 19$ using the above.

Comment: It's not a good idea to think as "mod" as a binary operation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so there is no way I can get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I try to take $(1\bmod 6)\bmod 7$. The first thing I have to do is take a representative of the residue class $1 \bmod 6$, so I might take $1,7,13,19,25,31,37$ and taking these modulo $7$ gives (the classes of) $1,0,6,5,4,3,2$ - so without more the operation you are describing is not well defined.

Comment: which one is given? Is it $(1\ mod\ 6)\ mod\ 7$?

Comment: @Sadhu Well you can't find $(1\bmod 6)\bmod 7$ from any data you have, because the value is not well defined. But look instead, if you want to, at $(1\bmod 7)\bmod 6 \in \{1, 8, 15, 22, 29, 36 \dots\} \equiv \{1,2,3,4,5,0\}$. Essentially the Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees that all outcomes are possible provided $b$ and $p$ are coprime.